# 'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, composer-php

I have forked a php application .they have instructed as follows.

**1.Application uses:**

- PHP 7.1.3
- composer
- laravel
- MySql or PostgreSQL

I have installed everything as per instructions.

2. Install and configure application by running following commands

   `composer install`

   `mv .env.example .env`

When I run `mv .env.example .env` as per instructions i get the following error

> 'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

any help or suggestions will be helpfull

Comment: `mv` is a Linux/Unix utility. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: aah bro  windows am using :(

Comment: Could simply replace that with `copy .env.example .env` and then `del .env.example` OR `move .env.example .env`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`mv` is a Unix command and I think you are using windows. You have 2 options:

1. Installing Git bash and in the bash use `mv` command.
2. Using Windows `move` command.

Comment: We all were newbies, you will learn more as you go. I strongly recommend to install Git, it's so handy. And if my answer helps, please mark it as answer.

Comment: Yes, I need to wait almost 6 minutes to accept your answer. :D

Comment: `git mv build/404/index.html build/404.html` But it throws `fatal: not under version control, source=build/404/index.html, destination=build/404.html`

Comment: remove the `git` from the command.